# Calculate the average of absolute values of a measurement with a measurement error

Tags: references, measurement-error, uncertainty, error-propagation, errors-in-variables

I have a few parameters; each is measured imprecisely with a known but unique random
measurement error. We can assume that the error is normally distributed, with mean 0 and known variance (different for each parameter).

I have two problems

1. I would like to estimate an average of these parameters. I think the solution here
   is easy; I can take the weighted average of these measurements, weighted by the inverse of the variance of the measurement error.
2. I would like to estimate an average of ABSOLUTE values of these parameters. I can't
   just calculate the weighted average because the errors will bias the final estimate. Large measurement errors will always result in large absolute values, moving the estimate away from its true value.

Is there a method to account for the bias caused by the measurement error?

Comment: That is not biased, that is accurate.

Comment: @PeterFlom if the true value is 0, and I measure it with an error, the absolute value will never be < 0, and the average will be > 0, therefore the results is biased, and the larger the error, larger the bias